# Unexpected "unexpected end of line" JavaScript lint warning

Tags: javascript, lint

This is my JavaScript (much stripped down):

```
function addContent() {
    var content = [];
    content.append(
        makeVal({
            value : 1
        })
    ); // Generates lint message
}
```

Running a lint program over this, I get the message

```
unexpected end of line; it is ambiguous whether these lines are part of the same statement
```

on line 7. If I concatenate lines 6 and 7 the message goes away.

Can anyone explain where this ambiguity is? It seems to me that the parenthesis on line 7 is unambiguously closing the call to append().

Comment: which lint program are you using? sounds to me like you need to file a bug report for it.

Comment: I would rather say that *content* is undefined at that moment.

Comment: This would be more readable to me makeVal({"value" : 1})

Comment: Yes, 'content' was undefined. I started with a much larger piece of code and chopped it down for this example. Similarly, the object originally had ten members, which is why I didn't have the entire makeVal() call on one line.

Comment: I think it might be **too** stripped down. JSLint (probably the best known Lint for JS) doesn't complain about new lines there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that way to me, too. Sounds like a bug in the lint program you're using.

You can understand why it would wonder, because the call to `makeVal` fits the profile of code that's relying on semicolon insertion — unless you look correctly at the wider context and realize it's within argument list for the `append` call. Seems to me the lint program is not actually parsing the language, just looking for patterns, which **is** going to mean it's going to have both false positives and false negatives.